# What is this "err.(*exec.ExitError)" thing in Go code?

Tags: syntax, go

For instance, in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385867/20654

```
...
if exiterr, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
...
```

What is that `err.(*exec.ExitError)`  called? How does it work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's type assertion. I can't explain it better than [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Comment: Thanks. In that sense is it similar to a cast?

Comment: Well, only "similar." Casting is called [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) in Go. It may be right to say that conversion happens at compile-time, and assertion at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

It's a type assertion. That `if` statement is checking if `err` is also a `*exec.ExitError`. The `ok` let's you know whether it was or wasn't. Finally, `exiterr` is `err`, but "converted" to `*exec.ExitError`. This only works with `interface` types.

You can also omit the `ok` if you're 100000 percent sure of the underlying type. But, if you omit `ok` and it turns out you were wrong, then you'll get a `panic`.

```
// find out at runtime if this is true by checking second value
exitErr, isExitError := err.(*exec.ExitError)

// will panic if err is not *exec.ExitError
exitErr := err.(*exec.ExitError)
```

The `ok` isn't part of the syntax, by the way. It's just a boolean and you can name it whatever you want.