# How can Go type ExitError in package os/exec support the Sys() method if it's not in the documentation?

Tags: go, error-handling

Based on various examples on the web and in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385551/get-exit-code-go) SO question, I am trying to figure out how it is possible for type **ExitError** from package **os/exec** to support the **Sys()** method even if the docs only mention the **Error()** method for this type.

I've guessed that the **Sys()** method in question is from type **ProcessState** in package **os**, but how does **ExitError** get to use it directly (`exiterror.Sys()`) without having to use the full (`exiterror.ProcessState.Sys()`)?

This must be a basic Go question but I've yet to figure out the answer to this one one my own...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd.Wait()` already returns error of type `*ExitError`. If you look at `ExitError`'s definition, you can see that it embeds `*os.ProcessState`:

```
type ExitError struct {
        *os.ProcessState
        // other fields
}
```

It is through `*os.ProcessState` that a value of type `ExitError` can call `Sys()` method.

Note that within the definition of `ExitError`, there is no field name associated with `*os.ProcessState`, which means that a value of type `ExitError` can directly call any method on `*os.ProcessState` (sort of like inheritance, where `ExitError` inherits `*os.ProcessState`. But this is only to give you a very basic idea. Read the docs for clarification.) as long as there is no method defined on `ExitError` with the same name.

There is of course more to it. You can read about it [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

Comment: A-ha! My issue was two-fold: 1) I hadn't picked up on the fact that `*os.ProcessState` was an anonymous field, and that 2) this meant that `ExitError` therefore "inherited" `*os.ProcessState`'s fields and methods via embedding. That last link you included is what steered me in the right direction and pushed me to search for more info on the subject. It is now clear for me how this works. The way I now understand it is that `exiterror.Sys()` is a "shortcut" to `exiterror.ProcessState.Sys()` because of embedding. Thanks!