# how to pass os/exec output to gin get

Tags: go

I want to pass the exit code of an OS command to the URL. I'm using gin but I'm open to any way.

I just want to pass the err to the HTTP response.

As of yet, I'm not able to find an example for putting os output into HTTP response example so I've come here in the hope someone knows.

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "os/exec"
)
func Homepage(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "Hello World"
        }
}

func Powershell(c *gin.Context) {
    // Run this powershell program from Go.
    cmd := exec.Command("powershell","-file","C:\\temp\\test.ps1")
    // Wait for the Powershell program to exit.
    err := cmd.Run()
    //fmt.Println("Finished:", err)}


    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
      "Message": "This is the PowerShell exit code not the script exit code",
      "Finished:", err

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", Homepage)
    r.GET("/app", Powershell)
    r.Run()
}
```

So far everything I've tried just error on the get /app

Comment: So what problem are you having? What is the output you see? What do you expect instead?

Comment: I was just trying to return the exit code.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding a full response of your command suitable to you, you can do it with following code:

```golang
func Powershell(c *gin.Context) {
    cmd := exec.Command("powershell","-file","C:\\temp\\test.ps1")

    stdout, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "Message": "Error occurs",
            "Finished": err,
        })
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "Message": string(stdout),
            "Finished": nil,
        })
    }
}
```

But if you want to get just a numeric code you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385551/get-exit-code-go). I cannot test this solution in windows and cannot guarantee it will work in your case.

Comment: Thanks, Marten, that really helped.